# install opencv on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I've been trying to install `opencv`, using this [referance](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/). But when I try to run `make` command, I get error as follows:

```
/opt/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_dc1394_v2.cpp:59:10: fatal error: 
dc1394/dc1394.h: No such file or directory
#include <dc1394/dc1394.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:278: recipe for 
target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dc1394_v2.cpp.o' 
failed
make[2]: *** 
[modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dc1394_v2.cpp.o] Error 
1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6307: recipe for target 
'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried so many times to install `opencv`, when the installation is completed, I tried to check the installation, and then I get error that there is no module named `opencv`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use this [guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/) to download the OpenCV Libary to the linux. (ubuntu 18.04).

I did it today on my ubuntu 18.04 and it worked perfectly, but please read all the guide and don't just copy the terminal commands.

Comment: have you installed opencv in debug mode. If yes what is the corect way have you followed for the same.As I am able to installed opencv in release mode and not able to debug that code.